# Define reducer inside the component function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-reducer

Is it a valid and safe to define a reducer function inside the components' function (render phase)?

```js
const Component = () => {

  // is this okay to be here or should be outsite the function?
  const reducer = (state, action) => {
    // do stuff
  }

  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initState);

  return (
    <div />
  )
}
```

The reason I want to do this is because I need access the component's props. If this usage isn't correct, how do I access the props in the reducer?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a best practice, and honestly, I'm not sure if it would work -- at least, if the purpose is to access state directly, instead of passing it in via an action. The purpose of Redux is "pure" state management. That means you take an input (an "action", with all the state information needed to update the Redux store), apply it, and create a new object to represent the state of your program.

So instead of accessing the state directly, you pass along all of the variables you need in a action.

You can see example code, and some more carefully worded explanation here:
https://redux.js.org/understanding/thinking-in-redux/three-principles